# Turn a NSDecimalNumber negative

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I am looking for a way to turn a `NSDecimalNumber` negative by multiplying by `-1`.

```
/* decNumber is the one I would like to turn negative */
NSDecimalNumber *decNumber = [values objectAtIndex:billIndex];

NSDecimalNumber *minusOne = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInt: -1];
finalValue = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal: [[decNumber decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy: minusOne] decimalValue]];
```

This works but it feels like it's just too much for such a simple logic. Can you think of a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use [NSDecimalNumber>>decimalNumberWithMantissa:exponent:isNegative](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000179-decimalNumberWithMantissa_exponent_isNegative_) to generate -1 more concisely.

```
/* Answers (aDecimal x -1) */
NSDecimalNumber* negate(NSDecimalNumber *aDecimal) {
    return [aDecimal decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:
                    [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa: 1
                                                      exponent: 0
                                                    isNegative: YES]];
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"-1"]`?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale - that would work as well.  It might not be as efficient, but creating new objects simply as temporaries isn't that efficient anyway.

Comment: @DShawley, cool thanks. I think it's a bit more readable with the string method. But, I think the name of the method, `negate`, makes it clear anyway, so I'll go with your solution to be more efficient. Thanks! :)

Comment: For what its worth, i like the decimalNumberWithString by Matt. It does read easier. It might be less efficient but I like easy to read stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the answer by D.Shawley, but extension and swift style.

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    /* Answers (aDecimal x -1) */
    func decimalNumberByNegating() -> NSDecimalNumber {
        return self.decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy(NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 1, exponent: 0, isNegative: true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using bridge `as`

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {

    func decimalNumberByNegating() -> NSDecimalNumber {
        return -(self as Decimal) as NSDecimalNumber
    }
}
```