# Convert NSDecimalNumbers to Negative

Tags: swift, ios8, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber

Working on a budget app in swift.

Essentially, there is a label that displays keypad textInput to currencyStyle and displays this number ($5.00), then waits for user to choose Debit or Withdraw. If debit, number is appended to Table, but I'm lost when it comes to Withdraw(-).

I would like to

1. Convert NSDecimalNumber which is formatted as currency to a negative for appending to a tableView: String ($5.00 to -$5.00).
2. Convert NSDecimalNumber value to a negative and add to an NSNumber array that is storing numbers to be calculated for an available balance (5.50 to -5.50)

For both I have tried using NSNumberFormatter negativePrefix and a few other properties in Apple Documentation to no avail. Even tried creating a negative NSNumber value = -100.0, but app crashed during division.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057939/turn-a-nsdecimalnumber-negative

Comment: Does decimalNumberWithMantissa work in Swift? Can't find it in Xcode or Apple Swift Documentation...

Comment: You will need to initialise the -1 `NSDecimalNumber` like this in Swift: `NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 1, exponent: 0, isNegative: true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To easily negate the `NSDecimalNumber` create an extension in Swift like this:

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    func negative() -> NSDecimalNumber {
        return self.decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy(NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 1, exponent: 0, isNegative: true));
    }
}
```

You can then just negate your `NSDecimalNumber` like this:

```
yourNumber = yourNumber.negative()
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can also subtract its own value from zero and return it as follow:

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    var negative: NSDecimalNumber { NSDecimalNumber.zero.subtracting(self) }
}
```

---

```
NSDecimalNumber(value: 15.6).negative  // -15.6
```

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `-` operator. For example:

```
prefix func -(number: NSDecimalNumber) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    return number.decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy(NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 1, exponent: 0, isNegative: true))
}
```

You can then use this like so:

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(double: 5.00)
let negativeNumber = -number
```

Comment: Awesome! Didn't think about simply modifying the - operator!